# Google Places bump using jQuery $.post gives error : HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: jquery, google-places-api

I'm using google places and trying to send a bump(or check-in) request to google api.

```
bumpReference = {"reference" : "referenceIdObtainedFromNearbySearch"};

$.post('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/bump/json?sensor=true&key=MyApiKeyGoesHere',bumpReference,
                function(data)
            {
                alert(data.status);//should return OK on success 
            });
```

I'm getting a response of `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` for some reason. 
Ive checked the **key** and **reference** are correct.

This is what the [**official docs**](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#BumpRequests) say :
 
A Bump is an HTTP POST request of the following form:

```
POST https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/bump/json?sensor=true_or_false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere HTTP/1.1
Host: maps.googleapis.com

{
  "reference": "place_reference"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue at hand is called [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Places API is not designed to be used directly by JavaScript web applications, it is meant to be used by your server side infrastructure. As such, we have not enabled CORS access, and thus your browser rejects the POST.